# apache many frequent requests lock server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I setup a centos server by following howtoforge tutorials. It works fine but I noticed something and not sure how to solve it.

I open up Google Chrome open my site then press and hold F5 (refresh page) this makes browser send so many requests to server.

I check the log files and there are tens, hundreds of same url request from my ip. it doesn't even display requests like .js .css or image files. Just the address I refreshed and several lines one after the other like the one below.

This cause server to not respond after finish all.

I minimized sql queries to mysql and almost all data comes from APC cache. I enabled and checked the mysql query log and it runs only 2-3 queries per page display. rest comes from APC.

top command does not display high server load during this time but displays many apache processes.

How can I solve this issue? Is there a way to limit/block each ip not to request same url this many.

```
192.168.162.191 - - [06/Sep/2013:12:26:29 +0300] "GET /en/page1 HTTP/1.1" 200 10084 "http://domain.com/en/page1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36"
```

## EDIT 1

I pressed and holded F5 for 5 soconds and this happened. Server load normally is zero. No one is on server.

Page generation time is 200ms

Top output

```
top - 08:23:00 up 41 days, 11:32,  1 user,  load average: 0.12, 0.05, 0.01
Tasks: 490 total,   2 running, 488 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 27.9%us,  5.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 66.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2979104k total,  2141960k used,   837144k free,   178948k buffers
Swap:  3112952k total,    14112k used,  3098840k free,   775020k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
18293 web1      20   0  146m  27m  16m R 83.9  1.0   0:02.96 php-cgi
25247 mysql     20   0  213m  57m 4996 S 22.9  2.0   3:34.66 mysqld
18465 web1      20   0  143m  22m  13m S  9.3  0.8   0:00.28 php-cgi
18467 web1      20   0  143m  22m  13m S  9.3  0.8   0:00.28 php-cgi
18431 web1      20   0  143m  22m  13m S  4.6  0.8   0:00.14 php-cgi
31704 apache    20   0 25204 3648  708 S  1.3  0.1   0:01.10 httpd
31701 root      20   0  151m  20m  11m S  1.0  0.7   0:02.34 httpd
18295 root      20   0  2836 1304  864 R  0.7  0.0   0:00.13 top
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:12.50 ksoftirqd/1
 1378 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   5:12.68 iscsi_q_30
18200 apache    20   0  151m  13m 4668 S  0.3  0.5   0:00.01 httpd
18330 apache    20   0  151m  13m 4676 S  0.3  0.5   0:00.01 httpd
    1 root      20   0  2900 1316 1164 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.91 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:26.73 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   5:01.34 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
```

Output of `ps uax | grep httpd | wc -l` is 238 . Idle is at around 20.

Answer (score 0):

Provide plz these info:

page generation time

output of:

```
top
```

and

```
ps uax | grep httpd | wc -l
```

(maybe you need replace httpd with apache if u use debian)
in moment of problem

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I edited my question

Comment: 238 httpd childs is really much. We should find what job these childs do. lets try to monitor /server-status while load coming.

Answer (score 0):

apache + php/mysql is known to be ddosable by just pressing F5, if your setup is not tuned.

- check mysql with some mysql-tuning-script like mysqltuner or mysql tuning primer and adjust acccordingly
- check apache-error-logs
- use mod_evasive to prevent your server from beeing dos'd by accident
- use top/htop (for os), atop (for apache) and mytop (for mysql) to investigate the bottleneck
- tune -> check -> tune -> check -> tune -> check -> be happy :)

Comment: yes trying to configure fail2ban and/or mod_evasive now to see how they perform. I'll keep question updated.

Comment: mod_evasive is by default *very* restrictive; soi just keepoing F5 pressed will likely result in error.403, but settings can be adjusted.

Comment: yes what I'm trying now with mod_evasive is to add ip to firewall for a period of time then expire, like I do with fail2ban. But couldn't succeed yet :/ . I guess I'll ask another question about this.